# Command history lost

Tags: linux, administrator, command-history

Is there a way to know if someone (including system administrators) has deleted the bash commands history on purpose? (the `history -r` doesn't seem to work)
And is there any way to recover that history?

Comment: Have you checked the modified date on the history file, such as `~/.bash_history`

Comment: If they deleted the history then that command would be in the history.  There are far to many ways you could complicate that search though.

Comment: @Ramhound On some unix systems adding a space in from of a command prevents it being added to the history. You can also do tricks like `HISTFILE=/dev/null`. Then do your dirty deeds. Much more trickery can be found in [How to Clear the Logs & History on Linux Systems to Cover Your Tracks & Remain Undetected « Null Byte :: WonderHowTo](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/clear-logs-history-linux-systems-cover-your-tracks-remain-undetected-0244768/)

Comment: Short answer: No and no to the 2 questions in the question.